# JavaScript check if start button is clicked

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my button. I'd like to keep playing my opening sound if the button has not been clicked; otherwise pause the sound and load the game. How can I achieve this? I've tried this so far to no avail.

```
function showStartScreen(launch) {
    //SHOW SPLASH SCREEN
    var screen = document.getElementById("splash");
    removeClass(screen, SPLASHSTATES.SPLASH_OFF);
    addClass(screen, SPLASHSTATES.SPLASH_ON);

    if(document.getElementById('startButton').click = false){
    playSound(sndOpening);
    }
    else{
    //CONFIGURE START BUTTON
    var start = document.getElementById("startButton");
    if (launch) {
        start.innerText = "Start Game";
        stopSound(sndOpening);
        start.addEventListener("click", loadGame, false);
    } else {

    start.innerText = "Resume Game";
    start.addEventListener("click", reloadGame, false);
            }
    } // end of outer if-else

    //ANIMATE SPLASH SHOW
    animatePanel(splash);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks

Comment: You can't check whether an element was clicked once ago, you can only listen to events that will fire when it gets clicked. It you need a history, you will need to build it manually (a boolean variable in your case)

Comment: Why don't you just play sound always and on click stop sound?

Comment: @AlmirSarajčić that's was one of what I tried. But when I ran the app, it's not playing the sound.

Comment: Is this the code you ran?
In this code playSound is inside if block that would never be executed. You need to put it out.

Comment: no this is not the code I ran. it dont have if block

Answer (score 0):

You could bind your function to the onclick-attribute of the button like this:

```
<input type="button" id="startButton" value="Start game" onclick="showStartScreen(launch);" />
```

Or you assign your function to the DOM-Element of the button:

```
document.getElementById('startButton').onclick = showStartScreen;
```

The second approach demands to write the function name without parenthesis or parameters.

Comment: sry, you need to erase the parameter in the first example. Then it should do. At least it does so for me